# MS Word 2013: automatic figure caption numbering inside text boxes with text wrapping

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, table-of-contents

How can I obtain text-wrapped figures with automatically numbered figure captions in Word 2013?

In a two column MS Word 2013 document, I am placing figures and their captions in text boxes with text wrapping in order to keep the captions joint with the figure and determine the location on the page (I am used to LaTeX).

Updating all document fields through select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and <kbd>F9</kbd>, however, does not result in the figure caption fields inside the textboxes being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Left click on the figure in question and select "insert caption". The pop up allows you to pick what kind of numbering to use and should populate automatically as you add new captions to figures in the same word document.

Comment: Indeed, but as you place both figure and caption in a text box, you can no longer update the figure number through CTRL-a and F9, which works fine outside the text box

Answer (score -2):

What I do is that I copy the generated text from inside the text box, delete the text box, then paste it as text (keeping the format of course).

Comment: So are you saying that the OP ***cannot*** do what he describes with text boxes.  If so, you should **say so**, and ideally provide a reference.

Comment: OP, naturally, stated his problem. I provided a solution which is a way to have captions outside text boxes, as the OP wishes.